# What is a good way to make a React Dashboard as an Cloud Run app?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, dashboard, google-cloud-run

How would be a good way to approach the following setup:

I want a Cloud Run app acting as a Dashboard (React) where stats are fetched from an API (also a Cloud run app in the same project) and displaying them in the browser.

**Reason for the Dashboard to be a Cloud Run app**

The dashboard should only be accessed by authorised personel with certain roles. I have already setup all security measures, load balancer, IAP, IAM for accessing Cloud Run services. So far none of them have a GUI though.

**How I imagine it to work**

The dashboard is opened in the browser by calling an endpoint: `www.domain/dashboard/` of the Cloud Run app. This automatically goes through a LB, IAP, requiring authentication etc. When the endpoint (url) is reached the browser displays the dashboard, the dashboard also fetch data from the API app (with a service account) before rendering (this last part I know how to do)

**Question**

Is it a good idea to approach it like this?

How can I make the endpoints render React code?

example:

```
router.get('/dashboard/', async (req, res) => {
    // 1. prepare some data from the api
    // 2. Render some React view and pass the data
    res.send('OK');
});
```

Thank you

I know React pretty well, and I know how to communicate between Cloud Run services. What I dont know is how to combine these two in a good way.

Comment: Is your question about the security? Or about the dashboard serving?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to:

1. Use a docker container with ngnix
2. Make it copy your React app inside the public static directory served by nginx
3. Deploy the docker container as your Cloud run frontend service
4. Define and associate the IAM policies so that only the frontend service can invoke the backend one (no allow unauthenticated)

If you don't know/like nginx, you can do the same using expressjs static or similar approach of other frameworks.